geom_label_repel segment anchor point control
I'm using ggrepel::geom_label_repel and trying to get the end segment line to attach to the same left aligned location on the label boxes. I have a dataset with varying clustering scales and can't get a clean look. A similar question was asked here, but it was never answered.
This example shows the clean, left aligned appearance I'm aiming for:
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = abs(rnorm(10)),y=abs(rnorm(10)),lab = c(1:10)))+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(x=x,y=y,label = lab),
                            xlim = c(1.9,2),direction='y')+
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  xlim(c(0,2))


This example replicates data similar to mine:
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(abs(rnorm(10)),1),y=c(abs(rnorm(10)),10),lab = c(1:11)))+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(x=x,y=y,label = lab),
                            xlim = c(1.9,2),direction='y')+
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  xlim(c(0,2))



What would you like the 2nd chart to look like instead? I don't see the problem or what the obvious improvement should be.

Don't think that there is an option to achieve your desired result. After a look at the source code the side where the segments connect to the label box is chosen internally based on a heuristic and varies depending on the size of the graphics device. I think the best option would be raise a feature request on GH to add a parameter which allows the user to set the position for the connection.
